# Mysql - ORDER BY - Can to use condition?

Tags: mysql

I sort a list by date_modified desc

This problem is when a new record input, date_modified is null date 0000-00-00 00:00:00

So this record will be in bottom, not the top of list.

How to sort this ? :(

Note: i don't insert to date_modified with now date , because i have a field date_create

Comment: well when you add the record add the current date, as date modified, same as creation date

Comment: Have you another solution ? it will be used when haven't better solution

Comment: i added 2 alternative, check if this can work out for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORDER BY COALESCE(date_modified, date_created) DESC;

But, performance will be better if you set date_modified to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP when doing an INSERT, as was already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you need to fix the problem of null date on insertion. Why don't you set the date_modified = now at the time of insertion?

Comment: why not do the same for date modified. In fact, by general rule, modified is always set to date created when element is created the first time. Your app may be different, I am just talking in general sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things either sort by the creation date first, then last_modified

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY created DESC,last_modified DESC
```

OR you can add the default modified time to the current time

```
INSERT INTO table (....,last_modified)VALUES (....,NOW());
```

Now you can make the sorting easily